# Sencha CMD build process applied to an existing ExtJs 4.1 app

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-command

I am trying to retrofit sencha CMD's build environment to an existing EXTjs 4.1 app. All the coding conventions mentioned in http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/command_code are followed. However I get stuck during the compile stage with a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` error.

I am suspecting it could be a circular dependency but cannot be sure. Has anyone tried to use sencha CMD on an existing Ext app? 
Also can you tell me how to increase the memory used by Ant to run the build process?

Any hints or pointers to  more information are much appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have had a similar issue for about the same length of time as you. It looks like it's a problem with Sencha CMD 3.0 and 64-bit JVMs. You need to double the heap space. This link has an answer for increasing the heap size: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?251529-Java-Heap-Size

I will say that if you did not initially generate your app with the "sencha generate app" command, you will have a very difficult time. The directory structure is very fragile and must match exactly what the Sencha CMD utility is expecting.

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: thanks  @jefff999 , increasing the heap space did remove the error.  But I got stuck with other probems. Eventually I had to dismantle my older folder structure and use Sencha CMD from scratch.